# Is Association as a general principle of OOP include into itself more narrow Inheritance?

Tags: oop

Is Association the most general principle of interaction between classes in OOP and include into itself all other principles such as Inheritance, Composition and so on?

I have tried to find the answer, but sometimes me obtained an opposite statements from different resources.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we talk about the following connections between elements:

- **Association** and its two subtypes (**aggregation** and **composition**)
- **Dependency**
- **Generalization**
- **Realization**

Each of these associations has its own semantics and is not a parent for the others, except for the **association** for **composition** and **aggregation**.

In your context, I would say the most "general" relationship is **dependency** (this kind of a relationship, if we make a change to a particular element, then it is likely possible that all the other elements will also get affected by the change).

Comment: Well, inheritance (I suppose you mean generalization is Mr. Nik) is the aggregation. But how connected association and for an example inheritance? The one argument that generalization (inheritance I mean) is different thing from association, because in case of inheritance we talking about the same object and in case of association — about two objects, still I cannot understand it clearly for now...
Association should be more abstract than dependancy.

Comment: Hello @YaroslavParkhomenko, generalization (inheritance) is not aggregation. For example, you have a java class. Every field is association (it can be aggregation or composition). The type after keyword extends is inheritance. Type after implements is realization. Every import is a dependency. Every type of fields, extends, implements, parameters, etc. will be in import (dependency).

Comment: Greating Mr. nik0x1, why inheritance is not the aggregation when it is the aggregation? Are master and subclass connected? — Yes. If subclass will disappear, what will happens to master-class? — Nothing. Do subclass consist of master class as its part? — Yes. Can subclass exist without master-class? — No.

This is an exactly inheritance is a case of aggregation.

Comment: Perhaps these descriptions will help you understand the difference:

https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html
https://www.uml-diagrams.org/aggregation.html

Comment: Of course not, Mr. @nikox1, you provided link to engineeric specification, or at least an attempt to do that: "UML 2.4 and the newest UML 2.5 specifications provide no definition for inheritance.", as an answer to more abstract, more 'scientific' quest, not a vey wise idea in general, IMHO — obviously, inheritance is a form of aggregation, at least any human that starting to study cursed programming, and have minimal logical thinking will say so...
The we can or not to name inheritance as a form of association... This is the question, some stuff that I have read said 'no', reasin I have expla